# Why does this sed construct not insert anything into an empty file?

Tags: awk, sed

I ran into this `sed` construct that I think intends to insert content to line 1 of a text file - but it seems to only work if the file has existing content, and does nothing when the file is empty. Why? And what is a better construct that would agnostically insert text to line 1 of a file regardless of existing file content?

```
$ rm -f ./foo
$ touch foo
$ sed -i "1 i\hello world" foo
$ cat ./foo
$ echo "whatever" >> ./foo
$ cat ./foo
whatever
$ sed -i "1 i\hello world" foo
$ cat ./foo
hello world
whatever
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed operates on each line of the file but, if the file doesn't have any lines, sed doesn't operate.  As is often the case, awk provides more flexibility.

Try GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print"hello world"} 1' foo
```

The above will work regardless of whether `foo` is empty or not.

If you don't have GNU `awk` (`gawk`), then you need:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print"hello world"} 1' foo >tmp && mv tmp foo
```

### How it works

Before the start of any file on the command line, `BEGINFILE{print"hello world"}` writes `hello world`.  This happens whether the file is empty or not.

For every line in the file, `1` is awk's shorthand for print the line.

For GNU awk, `-i inplace` is the equivalent of sed's `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `sed`, you could do something like the following:

```
$ echo "FPM" >> foo; sed -i -e '1i\hello world' -e '$ d' foo
```

This will work regardless of whether `foo` exists or not, is empty or not empty.

The first command, `echo "FPM" >> foo`, appends the line "FPM" (can be any text you like) to the end of `foo` if `foo` exists; otherwise it creates `foo` and adds the line "FPM" to `foo`.

The second command, `sed -i -e '1i\hello world' -e '$ d' foo`, inserts "hello world" above the first line in `foo` and then deletes the last line of the file (which contains "FPM").